# Implement Oppwa payment integration with React Native

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, react-native-ios, aar

Has anyone implemeneted Oppwa payment with React Native
Actually I've to integrate HyperPay and STC Pay in my app.
Is there any easy way to done this?

Comment: What is `Oppwa`?

Comment: Oppwa is a payment platform check here https://wordpresshyperpay.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/mobile-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find procedure for **Android** and **IOS**
https://wordpresshyperpay.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/mobile-sdk/first-integration.

**Android**

Here you can download aar file to import through android studio(Open android folder in android studio as project otherwise linking will not work)

https://github.com/shardullavekar/peachpay/tree/master/oppwa.mobile-2.2.0

A helpful library https://github.com/kottiDev/react-native-oppwa

Comment: Hey Zuhair, I'm trying to integrate native sdk module in ios but I'm stuck:( can u help me in this case? I've followed this [article](https://medium.com/simicart-developers/integrating-hyperpay-into-a-react-native-project-72c688bd7161) can you help?

Comment: Yes Oliver what issue you are facing?